# Erro ao processar grandes imagens com o openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Estou tentando processar um ortomosaico, o problema é que a imagem é muito grande, com outros mapas menores consigo processar normalmente, mas quando vou processar um mapa maior ele da erro na conversão de RGB para HSV, mas esse erro ocorre porque ele não conseguiu ler a imagem logo esta tentando converter uma imagem vazia, por isso o erro.

esse é o código inicial e o erro apresentado é na linha de conversão de RGB para HSV...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imageName = "mapa.tif"

imagem = cv2.imread(imageName,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

erro:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3959
```

Obs.: Lembrando que com mapas menores o código funciona, por esse motivo acredito que possa ser algum limite de alocação de memória na função cv2.imread.

Alguém tem alguma informação sobre isso? ou sabe como aumentar o limite de alocação de memória para leitura de imagem no openCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já observou, seu problema é que `cvtColor` não está reconhecendo a imagem de entrada, provavelmente ele acha que `None` quando espera um imagem com pelo menos 3 canais de cor: `image.shape[2]` igual a 3 ou 4.

É estranho que o erro se dê apenas no `cvtColor`, eu esperaria que já no `imread` desse problema.

De toda forma, uma coisa que você pode fazer é ver qual o maior tamanho de imagem que o seu hardware consegue suportar. Para isso, você precisa checar o tamanho da imagem (`image.size`) e qual o tipo (`type(image)`). Com isso saberá o tamanho máximo da imagem que pode ser convertida.

Daí, você tem duas abordagens que dependem do que você quer fazer com essa imagem.
1) redimensionar a imagem (`resize`)
2) quebrar a imagem em partes menores, converter e depois juntar de novo. Como imagens são ndarrays, é só usar indíces para separar a parte do ndarray que você quer.

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda, acabei resolvendo o problema dividindo a imagem em varias partes. Mas não sei dizer exatamente o limite de tamanho para a operação.